# How to use linq if there are no record found?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a method that uses join between one table, but i am struggling as to how if there  are no records found on table from the database. I need some help on my linq query here in sense my join should join three tables and search if there no records to specific column(Year=1998). I have 3 tables here below for more details to my topic, i hope this can make sense.

```
      // Controller
             public ActionResult GetExtractionViewModelsNoParam()
                {
        
                    ProductionManagementEntities db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
        
        
                    var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                                        from m in db.Models
                                        join w in db.Weeks
                                        on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
        
                                        orderby w.Year ascending
                                        orderby w.WeekNum ascending
        
        
                                        
        
                                        select new ExtractionViewModel
                                        {
        
                                            Day = p.ProductionDate,
                                            Week = w.WeekNum,
        
                                             VW250 = m.Name,
                                            Year = w.Year
        
                                        }).ToList();
        
                    TempData["scheduleList"] = scheduleList;
                    return RedirectToAction("ExportToExcel");
        
                }
        
        // Model
          public class ExtractionViewModel
            {
                public string Year { get; set; }
        
                public int Week { get; set; }
        
                
                [DataType(DataType.Date)]
                public DateTime Day { get; set; }
        
               // public string VW240 { get; set; }
        
                public string VW250 { get; set; }
        
                public string VW270 { get; set; }
        
                public string VW2502PA { get; set; }
        
                public string VW270PA { get; set; }
            }
    
    // sql query
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
    SELECT TOP (1000) [WeekId]
          ,[WeekNum]
          ,[Year]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Week]
      where WeekNum = 53
      order by YEAR

SELECT TOP (1000) [ModelId]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Code]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[InActive]
  FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Model]

SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductionDayId]
      ,[WeekId]
      ,[ProductionDate]
      ,[DayOfWeek]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[InActive]
  FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[ProductionDay]
```

Comment: Have you tried to use where query to sort the records or any query to check if there are no values in your specific column?

Comment: I'm confused. Is your question "How do I craft a LINQ query that determines if there is a row in my table with Year = some number?" Your current LINQ query doesn't do any filtering.

Comment: Can you give an example of your database table schema and example records?

Comment: @gunr2171 i have shared the table from the database

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to do an outer join? If you provide a short list of sample data from each table, and what you are trying to get out in your final, viewmodel table, it may be clearer to understand.

Comment: Your variable scheduleList is a list, so you can just use Count to determine if there are any items in the list?

Comment: @Johanthan i have shared my samples of 3 different tables

Comment: @LordPupazz can you share your logic with me? I havent think of using count as a variable to determine that

Comment: @GcobaniMkontwana just use something like: if(scheduleList.Count() == 0) { // do something when the list is empty }